# Get or set file details programmatically

Tags: c#, file

Try going to any file, right clicking on it, and clicking on the "Details" tab. Like this photo
[image]

I want to change this values. Also Can I add custom properties the file details. Especially I want to do this changes for tif,jpeg,png,pdf files.
Can I see my custom properties in "Details" window?

I found this page but it can change only office files.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422

Comment: Windows Property System: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898.aspx

Comment: #RogerLipscombe, I will try it, Thanks for now

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). It has wrappers for the Windows Property System.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Eli Arbels answer, an example from the documentation from the Windows API Code Pack (which works very well for us):

```
IShellProperty prop = ShellObject.FromParsingName(fileName).Properties.GetProperty(propertyName);

if (prop.ValueType == typeof(string))
{
    (prop as ShellProperty<string>).Value = value;
}
```

Comment: in first line, I am getting this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

Additional information: The given CanonicalName is not valid.

Comment: @MuslumOzturk: please create a new question with code and sample.