# Win Api The given CanonicalName is not valid

Tags: c#, file, winapi

I am trying to add or change file property. Like this question:

[Get or set file details programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982898/get-or-set-file-details-programmatically/21985091)

but I am getting error. My OS is Windows 8.1. Isn't this code not working my OS.

My code:

```
ShellObject xml = ShellObject.FromParsingName(@"C:\Users\Muslum\Desktop\test.xml");
var writer = xml.Properties.GetPropertyWriter(); // throw exception in this line
//set value test 1
writer.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Subject, "Test subject");

//set value test 2
//writer.WriteProperty("Test", "Value");
writer.Close();
```

Error Message:

```
An unhandled exception of type   'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.PropertySystemException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

Additional information: Unable to get writable property store for this property.
```

Inner exception :

```
{"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try it with a file format that is actually capable of storing metadata.  Like a .jpeg file.  Not .xml, that's a fail whale.

Comment: I tried it with a jpg file but this time gave error next line. The error is "Additional information: Unable to set property.". Actually I need this in xml file. How can I do this in xml file?

Comment: This is probably because the file type does not have this property.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this failure, Muslum? This error is so frustrating